# Struct instance function pointer as function argument (kind of like std::bind in C++)

Tags: rust

I'd like to do something similar to C++ `std::bind` and pass a bound function pointer as an argument to another function.

The code below demonstrates my failed attempt and hopefully illustrates what I'm trying to do.

```
pub struct MyStruct {
    x: i64
}

impl MyStruct {
    pub fn struct_function(&mut self, val: i64) {
        self.x += val;
    }
}

fn normal_function(val: i64) {
    println!( "sum -> {}", val + 1);
}

fn do_something_with_a_function(f: fn(i64)) {
    f(23);
}

fn main() {
    // This works as you'd expect
    do_something_with_a_function(normal_function as fn(i64));

    // What I'd like to do
    // This attempts to use a closure, but throws an error.
    let instance = MyStruct{x: 0};
    let instance_function = |val: i64|{instance.struct_function(val)};
    do_something_with_a_function(instance_function as fn(i64));
}
```

Error:

> error: non-scalar cast: `[closure@src/main.rs:25:29: 25:72 instance:&mut MyStruct]` as `fn(i64)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is about the difference between a function pointer `fn(i64)`, which is just a pointer to some code, and a closure, which is an un-nameable struct with some data (context) and a call method.

To pass a closure, you need to make the function generic on callable types:

```
fn do_something_with_a_function<F: FnMut(i64)>(mut f: F) {
    f(23);
}
```

This says that it can take anything of a type which implements `FnMut(i64)`.  The `FnMut` means that it gets a mutable reference to its context when called, necessary to call mutable methods on it in this case (in other cases, `Fn` or `FnOnce` could be used; see [the book chapter on closures](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/closures.html)).  Ordinary functions also implement these traits.  `f` has to be `mut` for the same reason as the `FnMut` is needed.

Here's the updated caller:

```
fn main() {
    do_something_with_a_function(normal_function);

    let mut instance = MyStruct{x: 0};
    let mut instance_function = |val: i64|{instance.struct_function(val)};
    do_something_with_a_function(&mut instance_function);
    do_something_with_a_function(&mut instance_function);
}
```

Note that `instance_function` is now mutable and a `&mut` reference passed into `do_something_with_a_function()`.  If it's passed by value (which works once) it's moved, so you can't use it again.

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a9e09489f4d4edb64f95233e92773e3d&version=stable&backtrace=0))